# adding Google Maps API to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple question. I need to insert Google Maps API in my HTML. I am not able to do it in the Head section. Is that fine if I add that code fragment in Body before it is being used or what would be better solution?

Thanks

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false </script>
```

Comment: If the answer fixed your problem, please set the answer to solved. Thx

Comment: You should see a green check mark on the left of my answer. If you click on that, the question is marked as solved. This is one of the big advantages of stackoverflow. Every user can see if a question is already solved and if there are more than one answer, you can see the correct answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the best solution is to put it to the Head, but however if you can't do it then put it just before the closing body tag.

Just one more thing, you have to close your script tag '>' and end the string, like here:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the best solution is to put it to the head" ? It is not true - the best solution is to put it at the very end of the document. See [yahoo best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

Comment: This is true, you can put it in the body, as I already said. But I would recommend to make it like the W3C also recommend it. See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#idx-scripting_language-2)

Comment: External JS in the head, self-written script to the end of the body